# Equal Parameters without Comparison Operators

Tags: prolog

I'd like to create a predicate that evaluates if the two parameters entered are the same. Here's what I wrote (pretty basic)

```
same(A, B) :- A == B.

same(21, 21) % true
same(var, 'var') % true
same(var, 'Var') % false
```

I would like to do it **without using comparison operators** but I have no idea how. Any tips for me?

Comment: Look at the source code for the comparison operators. SWI-Prolog is on GitHub.

Comment: Is there a reason `same(X, X).` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Terminology is important here. What does it mean for parameters to be *the same* versus *equal* (as you mention in your comment to the answer @PauloMoura gave), versus *unifiable*, which is probably what your professor really meant. These are not always the same thing in Prolog. DanielLyons gave you the right way to indicate two parameters are *unifiable*: `same(X, X)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd question. What's the point of not using comparison operators? Assuming, from your `same/2` predicate definition, that you want to test for term **equality**, one solution is:

```
same(A, B) :- sort([A, B], [_]).
```

But this is a **trick** that takes advantage of the standard `sort/2` predicate using term equality when performing term comparisons for sorting. As such, this (or any other similar trick) is not a sensible programming solution. What's the context of your question?

Comment: Nice trick over there. I'm not quite sure about the context, the professor said that I should check if the parameters are equal without using any comparison operator. That's weird right?